# Delete row with cells consisting of only one single space

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text document with delimiter ';'.

I have imported the values into an Excel file. Some of the fields have blank values only with single space.

I have tried the below code to delete blank cell but it doesn't pick as there is a space in the cells.

How do I remove the entire row with the blank cells with single space via macros?

Comment: You forgot to add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code for example :)

```
 Sub DeleteRowIfSpace()
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set rng = Sht.UsedRange
    Set MyRange = rng

        For Each mycol In MyRange.Columns
            For Each mycell In mycol.Cells
                If mycell.Value = " " Then
                mycell.EntireRow.Delete
               End If

            Next
        Next
    Next
    End Sub
```

This code loops through all sheets in a workbook looking for " " and delete the row.